# switch mysql binary logs after 15 minutes

Tags: mysql

I am new to Mysql. Please let me know the parameter to switch binary logs every 15 minutes so that max data loss will be only 15 minutes. Moreover how can we change default size of bin log files from 1GB to 50 or 100 MB. what will be the consequences of above changes.

Answer (score 0):

By default binlog being synced on disk with every commit, thus, you can lost only the latest transaction in case of failure, and there's no need in rolling it every 15.

Moreover, there's no such option to configure. One can only tune the size of binlog file with `max_binlog_size` variable, and the number of days before automatic removal of binary log files with `expire_logs_days` one.

Although, it's a bad idea, a  `FLUSH BINARY LOGS` command can be issued via cron, for instance, with any schedule needed.